# Post to Facebook group from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I´m looking for an answer if it´s possible to post all blog posts to a Facebook group from the profile that is logged in on my site?

I have a site where people register with their Facebook account and then they can create blog posts through a form made with Gravity Forms. I would like these blog posts to be published automatically on a Facebook group that administer.
I have created an Facebook app with publish_actions permissions.

To post from my site to Facebook I have tested a lot of plugins but all of them publish the posts from my Facebook account and not from the logged in user.

So my question is if someone know how to grant my app/website permissions to post publicly as the logged in user on the Facebook group?

Best regards
Melker